# How to trigger handlers (notify) when using import_tasks?

Tags: ansible

When using `notify` on a task using `import_tasks` the handlers are not fired. I'm wondering why. `tags` are working like expected.

How to trigger handlers on imported tasks?

Example:

playbook test.yml:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  handlers:
  - name: restart service
    debug: 
      msg: restart service

  tasks:
  - import_tasks: test_imports.yml
    notify: restart service
    tags: test
```

test_imports.yml

```yaml
- name: test
  debug:
    msg: test
  changed_when: yes

- name: test2
  debug:
    msg: test2
  changed_when: yes
```

Expected:

```
> ansible-playbook -i localhost, test.yml

PLAY [all] *************************************************************************************************************

TASK [test] ************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "test"
}

TASK [test2] ***********************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "test2"
}

RUNNING HANDLER [restart service] **************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "restart service"
}

...
```

Actual:

```
> ansible-playbook -i localhost, test.yml        

PLAY [all] *************************************************************************************************************

TASK [test] ************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "test"
}

TASK [test2] ***********************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "test2"
}

...
```

Answer (score 2):

This question has been partially answered in Ansible's bug tracker here:

> `import_tasks` is processed at parse time and is effectively replaced by the tasks it imports. So when using `import_tasks` in handlers you would need to notify the task names within.

<sup>*Source: mkrizek's comment: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/59706#issuecomment-515879321*</sup>

---

This has been also further explained here:

> imports do not work like tasks, and they do not have an association between the `import_tasks` task and the tasks within the imported file really. `import_tasks` is a pre-processing trigger, that is handled during playbook parsing time. When the parser encounters it, the tasks within are retrieved, and inserted where the `import_tasks` task was located. There is a proposal to "taskify" includes at [ansible/proposals#136](https://github.com/ansible/proposals/issues/136) but I don't see that being implemented any time soon.

<sup>*Source: sivel comment: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/64935#issuecomment-573062042*</sup>

---

And for the good part of it, it seems it has been recently fixed: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/73572

---

But, for now, what would work would be:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  handlers:
  - name: restart service
    debug: 
      msg: restart service

  tasks:
  - import_tasks: test_imports.yml
    tags: test
```

And a *test_imports.yml* file like:

```yaml
- name: test
  debug:
    msg: test
  changed_when: yes
  notify: restart service

- name: test2
  debug:
    msg: test2
  changed_when: yes
  notify: restart service
```

This all yields:

```
PLAY [all] *******************************************************************************************************

TASK [test] ******************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => 
  msg: test

TASK [test2] *****************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => 
  msg: test2

RUNNING HANDLER [restart service] ********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: restart service

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

Then if you want to import those tasks somewhere this handler is not defined you could use the environment variable [`ERROR_ON_MISSING_HANDLER`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#error-on-missing-handler)  that helps you transform the error thrown when there is a missing handler to a "simple" warning.

e.g.

```
$ ANSIBLE_ERROR_ON_MISSING_HANDLER=false ansible-playbook play.yml -i inventory.yml

PLAY [all] *******************************************************************************************************

TASK [test] ******************************************************************************************************
[WARNING]: The requested handler 'restart service' was not found in either the main handlers list nor in the
listening handlers list
changed: [localhost] => 
  msg: test

TASK [test2] *****************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => 
  msg: test2

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```